# MacOS上のPython,kinterで作成したmenuにフォーカスできない。どうすれば良いですか？

Tags: python, macos, gui

MACで以下のPythonコードでメニューを作りたいのですが、

```
#!/usr/local/anaconda/bin/python
  
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Menu

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Python GUI")

win.winfo_toplevel()
menuBar = Menu(win)
win['menu']=menuBar

fileMenu = Menu(menuBar)
menuBar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_cascade(label="Exit", command=win.quit())

win.mainloop()
```

実行するとメニューには’File'という文字は出て来ますが、その上にカーソルを移動してクリックしてもサブメニューの'Exit'が現れません。また、左上のアップルアイコンもクリック出来ないです。どこか環境設定が足りないのか？教えて下さい。

Comment: `作成したmenuにフォーカスできない。`というのはどういう状況で何が出来ないということでしょう？ Windows10のPython3.8.3ではマウスやキーボードで選択出来てドロップダウンメニューも表示できるようですが。

Comment: カーソルをFileのメニュー上に置いてクリックしてもExitのサブメニューが出てこない、左上のアップルマークもクリックできないです。

Comment: こんなチュートリアルサイトがあるようなので参考にしてみてはどうでしょう？ [Tkinter チュートリアル - メニューバー Menubar](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/tutorial/tkinter-tutorial/tkinter-menubar/)

Comment: 上記のシンプルなプログラムを開始した直後ではメニューバーにアクセス出来ないのですが、別のアプリケーション、例えばターミナルをアクティブにした後に戻るとメニューが正しく出て来ます。これってOSの問題ですか？それともPython/tkinterの問題？

Comment: OS(あるは何かIDEを使っていればそれ)の問題かもしれませんね。Windowsのコマンドプロンプトから実行した場合は表示されて選択出来ました。それから`command=win.quit()`の`quit`の`()`は付けておくと終了出来ないバグになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。win.quitは '()' 無しに少し前に変更していました。